# GWT opening a file from a byte array in memory

Tags: java, gwt

Are there ways to receive a byte array or string array from the serverside to GWT client and open it as file?
The byte array is already in memory and we don't want to write it to a file in the server and pass the URL back to the client.
Thanks

Comment: Clarify the "open it as file" bit. File manipulation API is not supported by GWT obviously. But nothing is stopping you from getting the data from server via a normal RPC call.

Answer (score 0):

GWT Java is compiled into Javascript.

So, try writing a Javascript-based app first, to open your server file "as a file" by your Javascript client. Even if you do not know Javascript - then at least, perform a thought experiment:
- What are the limitations placed by the brosers
- Why do browser conventions place such limitations?

What your javascript app cannot do, so too your GWT app.

What you are thinking is to use File IO API to access your files sitting on the server. There are two possible reasons why you wish to do that:

1. You are familiar with File IO and you want to do on GWT Java what you have been doing for years with Java, and you are too fixated to change your perspective.
2. You want to write a web-based interface to your operating system, and you have grand plans for your app.

If you are in situation 1, you are lucky. You simply need to change your perspective to respect the *asynchronicity* and remoteness of thin-client-server communications.

But in the case that this is a Mt Everest that you have to climb and you still persist in trying File IO patterns on GWT, then you need to be prepared for a large project. I am saying "File IO patterns" rather than "file io" because you would have to emulate them. Obviously, browser security technology does not yet allow you to open a file on the browser's system. And for that reason, there is no point for GWT to supply that functionality.

Secondly, File IO belongs to the java.io realm. And again, browser security does not allow you most of the functionality of java.io. Without the set of file.io functionality on GWT, how then can you have File IO.

What you can do is to scale down on your expectations of File IO and write down a specification of what the features of File IO you would like to have. Like, open, close, read, etc. Then you write a some GWT Java classes to let you perform those little tit-bits of emulated file IO.

So just now, I decided to google "GWT inputstream outputstream" and there are some opensource projects out there from whom you could borrow/steal some code to achieve your life long fulfilling goal of emulating client-server file io thro GWT.

But my advice to you is, you should translate your spec of functionality into  a REST service. REST is how google docs is accessed. Study google data api and learn how they do it, including the authentication framework.